# Drawing the trajectories for a non-linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Find the critical points of the system and draw the trajectories, indicate if they are stable, asy. stable or unstable.

$dx/dt=x(1.5-x-0.5y)\\dy/dt=y(2-y-0.75x)$

My critical points are $(0,0) \;(0,2) \;(1.5,0) \;(0.8,1.4)$

I compute the Jacobian to get $$\begin{pmatrix} 1.5-x-0.5y & 0.5x\\ -0.75y & 2-2y-0.75x \end{pmatrix}$$

At each critical point I have

$J(P_1)=\begin{pmatrix}0.5 & 0\\0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \implies \lambda=0.5,2$

$J(P_2)=\begin{pmatrix}0.5 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}\implies \lambda=0.5,-2$

$J(P_3)=\begin{pmatrix} -1.5 & -0.75 \\ 0 & 0.875 \end{pmatrix}\implies \lambda=0.875,-1,5$

$J(P_4)=\begin{pmatrix} -0.8 & -0.4 \\ -1.05 & -1.4 \end{pmatrix}\implies \lambda\approx -.386,-1.81$

Ok so based on this information how do I draw the trajectories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your critical points.

Now, look at the signs of each of your eigenvalues. What can you tell about the type of curve from this linearization and these signs? Be careful with linearization for the marginally stable cases, but you are safe with the four critical points regarding stability.

Now, compare that to this phase portrait.

$~~~~~~~~~~$[image]

If you write the system as $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, you can then choose numbers to figure out the direction and magnitudes because you already know the type of critical point from the eigenvalues. You have:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{y(2-y-0.75x)}{x(1.5-x-0.5y)}$$

Comment: So like any point on the graph you posted would work? This is where I am confused... I know that (0,0) is unstable (0,2) is a saddle point as is (1.5,0) and (0.8,1.4) is stable. How can you hand draw this? Like I knew what was going on at each point but I didn't know how to connect them

Comment: you are asking for the name and author?

Comment: Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems by William E. Boyce and Richard C. DiPrima.

Comment: so its a bad bookk?